# Audio editor written in Java

Tags: java, portable, audio-editing

I'm looking for an audio editor written entirely in Java, without any dependencies that have to be installed.

A self-contained JAR file that I can run from anywhere, even on machines that do not allow users to install software or edit the registry, for example.

Applications like this already exist. For example, MindTerm for SSH/SFTP connectivity and ImageJ for graphics editing.

Is there something like that for audio file editing?

Comment: Which audio editing features do you need?